# Thymeleaf send property as a parameter

Tags: thymeleaf

I'm trying to pass a property value as a String parameter to a Thymeleaf fragment with no success:
My code is:

```
<div data-th-replace="views/fragments/myfragmentfile :: fragmentname (${#{checkout.paybutton.text}})"></div>
```

the fragment receiving the parameter is as follows:

```
<p data-th-fragment="fragmentname (buttonText)">
```

in the property file:

```
checkout.paybutton.text=Purchase
```

How can evaluate the property before is sent as parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
<div data-th-replace="views/fragments/myfragmentfile :: fragmentname (${__#{checkout.paybutton.text}__})"></div>
```